# find a matrix whose row echelon form is the same as the row echelon form of its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone help me with this textbook question: can you devise a nonzero matrix whose row  echelon form is the same as the row echelon form of its transpose? Thank you.

Comment: Row-echelon form is not unique. Did you mean the reduced-row echelon form?

Comment: The book say row echelon form. I am thinking of a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Find a non-zero square matrix that is in row echelon form and is equal to its transpose.